# Append data from two tables and remove duplicates (ignoring case) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Table 1 name: STAT

```
P2
--------
ABC     
def
ghi
```

Table 2 name: MI

```
P2
--------
abc     
def
GHI
```

I would like some help to create a new table to APPEND THESE TWO tables with the same column name 
and remove duplicates ignoring the CASE

Expected result
Output Table 3 name:Combined

```
P2
--------
ABC     
def
ghi
```

If the value is same in Table 1 and 2, and only the case is different, then in the combined table, the equation can pick up any value (i.e from first or second table but not both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION, a setwise operator, is made for this purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS
(
    SELECT p2 COLLATE utf8_general_ci FROM STAT
     UNION
    SELECT p2 FROM MI
)
```

This assumes the two tables both use the utf8 character set. The COLLATE clause overrides the default collation for the UNION operation with a case-insensitive one per your requirement to ignore the case.

If your tables store data in some other character set, you need a collation appropriate to that character set.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `UNION`.

```
SELECT p2 FROM stat
UNION
SELECT p2 FROM mi
```

will give you only the distinct rows while `UNION ALL` would also give you the duplicates:

```
SELECT p2 FROM stat
UNION ALL
SELECT p2 FROM mi
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wVrXUDWpqvwRgTCCwoPd7x/0)